# Howto append new value pair to existing json object in lawnchair

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I was looking documentation at [Lawnchair website](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) and I am trying to figure out how do I insert new value pair to existing data.

Following sample in Lawnchair website.

```
var people = new Lawnchair('people'); 
var me = {name:'brian'};
people.save(me);
```

Now if I want to add "brian" age.

I kind of expected having something like `people.append("{key:mykey, age:30}")` but looks like there is no such a method?

Is there any any other way to do this?

Comment: Try using the `save()` function again with the same key of 'brian'

Comment: I did that in first place. It removes "name" and puts "age" in its place. 

`people.save({key:'7123857F-6196-4F80-8EF3-0752C647DE70', age:'1'});

Object
age: "1"
key: "7123857F-6196-4F80-8EF3-0752C647DE70"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not much familiar with LawnChair, but to the extent I can understand it, I would suggest something like the following:

```
people.find('r.name == "brian"', function(r){
    //remove 'r' (from the main storehouse) here somehow, I dont know how.
    r.key = yourkey
    r.age=30
    people.save(r)
});
```

- Retrieve and save the entry
- Remove the entry
- add `age` field to the saved object
- save it back! :-)

Do tell me if that helps. :-)